# iOS Swift 4 - Twitter login button not doing anything - returns Thread 1 Sigabrt with no stack trace

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-oauth

I am in the process of integrating Twitter and Firebase into an ios version of my app.

I am currently able to setup a Twitter login button, but once I click it, I get the error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is my App delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:" r*******R", consumerSecret:"6*********m")




    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("yo")
    return Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

And here is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import TwitterKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion: { session, error in
        if (session != nil) {
            let authToken = session?.authToken
            let authTokenSecret = session?.authTokenSecret
            let credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: session!.authToken, secret: session!.authTokenSecret)
            print("check1")

            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("not signed in")
                    return
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("check2")
            print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)");
        }
    })
    logInButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(logInButton)

    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

plist:

```
   <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
            <string>twitterkit-r************R </string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>twitter</string>
        <string>twitterauth</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U6xl.jpg

I checked for any extra outlets with the ViewController but couldn't find any, as the viewcontroller is only this login button which I have to add programmatically

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks -T

Comment: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" The error message says a lot more than that. Give the whole thing, please.

Comment: @matt thanks for the response.  I wish it did say more.  I have my console set to all output, and that's all it gives me

Comment: OK. Did you try searching? I see a lot of good suggestions about what to do when your twitter login button crashes.

Comment: @matt yeah I've searched quite a bit.  I've read that mostly this is an issue with outlets in the storyboard that need to be deleted, but since I am adding this button programmatically I don't know how I can delete the "unused" outlets.  Right when I click the twitter button, nothing happens, I get an error on the class declaration line in AppDelegate.

Comment: @matt I added a screenshot of my storyboard

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your storyboard. Twitter Login buttons crash because of configuration problems.

Comment: @matt something in my info.plist maybe or is it something on the Twitter end?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve the issue by starting a new project from scratch.

Weird bug